# Drag listener on special shaped image

Tags: android, touch, drag, swipe

I have this image:[image]

And in Android I want to drag on the image and get the x and y. But only on the dark part (but a imageview/button is a rectangle). So a sort of round OnTouchListener.

How can I manage to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You able to do it by Get touched pixel color of ImageView.

```
So, Step you need:

 1. Get touched pixel color.

 2. Compare touched pixel color with your image color . it is black.
```

So, you able to touched position in your desire image view position or not.

Thanks

Comment: Search google via this keyword "Get touched pixel color of ImageView in android"